# string concatenation using double quote within function bracket

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I suppose to use the function like this `$function.share("msg");` but i want to concatenate a variable with the strings.

```
$function.share("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+$Id+"");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What error do you get? What are you expecting to happen? What is the value of `$Id`? Also, the trailing empty quotes are needless cruft.

Comment: How "it doesn't work"? Any errors in JS console?

Comment: Are you sure you are using JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add double quotes around $Id? If so just do: $function.share("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + String.fromCharCode(34) + $Id + String.fromCharCode(34));

Comment: escaping the characters would be easier; $function.share("youtube.com/watch?v=\"" + $Id + "\"");

Comment: @DavidP: No, that's completely uncomprehensible. Just do `"youtube.com/watch?v=\"" + $Id + "\""` or `'youtube.com/watch?v="' + $Id + '"'`.

Comment: Bergi - escaping characters is certainly an alternative, but I always find it not as readable and not as comprehensible. I grant you that String.fromCharCode is rather long (Wish it were easier like vb - Chr(34).

Answer (score 0):

Choose your weapon

```
$function.share("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\""+$Id+"\"");
```

OR

```
$function.share('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="'+$Id+'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add quotes to it you can alternate between single quotes and double quotes like this:

```
$function.share('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="' + $Id + '"');
```